# How to crop a Pdf with printer/crop marks

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, crop, aspose

The Example PDF is: [PDF](http://speedy.sh/c3Ans/bre25419-cover.pdf)

Using Aspose.PDF for .NET, I'm trying to crop a PDF which has white spaces around the edges, and printer/crop marks. 
My first approach was to find out the dimensions of the Art box, media box, trim box, crop box; and try to figure out if any of these boxes didn't include the white space, so i could just crop that out and save as a new PDF.

However this PDF doesn't have the ArtBox/TrimBox correctly set. So i can't take this approach.

My Next though was to manually crop the PDF with respect to the printer/crop marks at the edges. However I'm unable to locate these elements inside the PDF using Aspose.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case  TrimBox == ArtBox == BleedBox == MediaBox [0 0 1642.5 1035]. There is no CropBox, so you can try to change MediaBox values,it used instead of CropBox by default (say with help of iText).

I have changed MediaBox a bit [72 72 1570.5 963]:
[image]

Comment: Thanks stanlyF, for the reply, but i am looking for a way to automate cropping PDF's printer marks for thousands of PDFs without relying on the art box, crop box as some of the PDF have invalid coordinates for these boxes.

Comment: Your PDF file contains PrinterMarks that drawn as a simple line segments(must be **PrinterMark** for a printer’s mark annotation). So you can not identify them with help of pdf parsing .

Answer (score 1):

The below Aspose.Pdf for .NET example will crop your PDF and remove the printer marks.

```
Aspose.Pdf.Document document = new Aspose.Pdf.Document(dataDir + "bre25419_cover.pdf");
//Iterate through All Pages of a PDF Document
for (int i = 1; i <= document.Pages.Count; i++)
{
    Aspose.Pdf.Rectangle cropBox = document.Pages[i].CropBox;
    // Crop percentage of width and height
    double percentageX = 4.4f / 100 * cropBox.URX;
    double percentageY = 6.7f / 100 * cropBox.URY;
    // update page's crop box
    document.Pages[i].CropBox = new Aspose.Pdf.Rectangle(cropBox.LLX + percentageX, cropBox.LLY + percentageY, cropBox.URX - percentageX, cropBox.URY - percentageY);

    Console.WriteLine("cropBox.LLX: " + cropBox.LLX + "\ncropBox.LLY: " + cropBox.LLY + "\ncropBox.URX: " + cropBox.URX + "\ncropBox.URY: " + cropBox.URY);
}
// save document         
document.Save(dataDir + "bre25419_cover_Output.pdf");
```

I work as a Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Thanks Saqib for the reply, This works for one PDF but i am looking for a way to automate this process for thousands of PDF with different margins, so i need a way to dynamically find the off set from the printer margin and then using that value i would crop.

Comment: Is there a way to find the edges of the printer marks, then assign the coordinate of the pdf size to these values?

Comment: I have updated the example code that uses a percentage value, instead of fixed values. Please see if this could help. Ideal solution would be to detect the 4 black lines on top, bottom, left and right edges, but this would require image processing.